# Show that the map is a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a set $M = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 | x^2+y^2-z^2=1\}$ and a function $\alpha \colon M \to S^1 \times \mathbb R$,
$$\alpha(x, y, z) = \left(\frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{1+z^2}},z\right)$$

Is there a smart method of showing that $\alpha$ is a diffeomorphism? I already showed that $M$ is an immersed submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$.

Is it enough to show that it is a bijection, the map is smooth, and the jacobian is nowhere 0?

Comment: $\alpha$ looks like sterographic projection but with a one-sheet hyperboloid ($H_1$) taking the place of a sphere.

Comment: A comment about terminology: the word you want in English is "map" (for the French term "application"). The English word "application" means something entirely different.

Answer (score 2):

Writing $\alpha(x,y,z) = (u,v)$ with $u \in S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\alpha^{-1}(u,v) = (\sqrt{1 + v^2}u,v)$. Now just verify that both $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ are smooth.

Comment: which charts and maps should I use to verify their smoothness?

Comment: @JonathanBaram: Note that both your manifolds, considered as submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^3$, have rotational symmetry around the $z$-axis. Hence, it will be the easiest to use charts that describe both as surfaces of revolution.

Comment: could you develop what it means to have charts that describe as surface of revolution

Comment: I showed that $M$ is an immersed submanifold of $R³$, cant I use this ?