# problem 4 in Alan Pollak and Guillmin differential topology.

Tags: general-topology, functions, differential-topology

Let $a > 0$, and set $B_a = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x|^2 < a \}$. Let $\phi : B_a \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by $\phi(x)  = \frac{ax}{\sqrt{a^2 - |x|^2}}$. Prove that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism of $B_a$ onto $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am stucked in proofing that the above function is 1-1 and onto because in the definition of  the function the scalar part depends on the norm of **x** as a vector, so if I equate 2 functions say one of them of **y** and the other of **x** there will be a difference in the scalar value on both sides so what shall I do?

related links:
 [Show that the map is a diffeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997912/show-that-the-map-is-a-diffeomorphism)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Show that the map $\psi : \Bbb R^n \to B_a$ defined by the equation
$$\psi(y) = \frac{ay}{\sqrt{a^2 + \lvert y\rvert^2}}$$ is the inverse of $\phi$.

Comment: Is that a prove for showing 1-1 & onto ..... how?

Comment: Yes. Since $\psi(\phi(x)) = x$ for all $x\in B_a$, $\phi$ is one-to-one; since $\phi(\psi(y)) = y$ for all $y\in \Bbb R^n$, $\phi$ is onto.